# TypeError: nameList.map is not a function by using antd validateFields() and getFieldValue get value null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Everything worked well before i add `validateFields()`and rule, now i receive an error`TypeError: nameList.map is not a function`,  also i am trying to use async/awit, i am not sure why it happened, the previous code is working perfectly without `validateFields()`, on the other hand i use `getFieldValue('categoryName')`to get input value,   it was working fine for few times at the beginning and then the value is null. i could not find any clue after i do the research.
please someone help me.

```
  updateCategory = () => {
    //hide confirm box
    this.formRef.current.formRef.current.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.setState({
          showStatus: 0,
        });
        const categoryId = this.category._id;
        const categoryName = this.formRef.current.formRef.current.getFieldValue(
          'categoryName',
        );
        //Reset fields to initialValues
        this.formRef.current.formRef.current.resetFields();
        //request to update category
        const result = await reqUpdateCategory({ categoryId, categoryName });
        if (result.status === 0) {
          //reload display list
          this.getCategorys();
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: try logging `nameList` that might not be array, in `this.formRef.current.formRef.current` why you are using `formRef.current` two times ?

Comment: Welcome to SO Daniel. The code snippet you shared doesn't include `nameList.map` code in it ? are we missing something ?

Comment: @Abhishek Ghosh thanks, `nameList.map` does not come with my code. It comes from below code. 
`TypeError: nameList.map is not a function
FormStore.validateFields
D:/Web/workspace/react-admin_client/node_modules/rc-field-form/es/useForm.js:658
  655 | _this.warningUnhooked();
  656 | 
  657 | var provideNameList = !!nameList;
> 658 | var namePathList = provideNameList ? nameList.map(getNamePath) : []; // Collect result in promise list                 ^  659 | 
  660 | var promiseList = [];
  661 | `

Comment: thanks for helping me, @shubham jha   `namelist` does not come from my code. i use `this.formRef.current.formRef.current` as  the Form is from child component, i use it in the parent component. i did research that antd form method is working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it works for me.
However, I noticed that the first parameter of the callback function is actually "values" instead of `err` since the error would now be caught by the `catch` callback of the promise.

Answer (score 4):

Just happened to come across this, so this is primarily for anyone that comes later, but `validateFields` does not take a function as a parameter. The signature for validatFields is `function (nameList, options)`. Name list is the list of fields that you want to valdiate.

If you don't provide a parameter, it uses the fields in the form itself. I believe what you want to do here is `.validateFields().then(async(err, values)=> { ... }` as below:

```javascipt
updateCategory = () => {
    //hide confirm box
    this.formRef.current.formRef.current.validateFields().then(async (err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.setState({
          showStatus: 0,
        });
        const categoryId = this.category._id;
        const categoryName = this.formRef.current.formRef.current.getFieldValue(
          'categoryName',
        );
        //Reset fields to initialValues
        this.formRef.current.formRef.current.resetFields();
        //request to update category
        const result = await reqUpdateCategory({ categoryId, categoryName });
        if (result.status === 0) {
          //reload display list
          this.getCategorys();
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that migrating from antd3->antd4, `validateFields` no longer supports callback, instead you should use the following piece of code:

```
validateFields().then(callback)
```